# Falta enviar datos del input a phpmyadmin (PHP)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Ayer con ayuda de miembros del foro logre mandar los datos del registro a la base de datos. El problema radica en que solo se envia el email, El usuario aparece como *root* y la contraseña esta en blanco, Reviso el Insert Into pero noto que estan todas las variables que se deberian enviar. Que debo hacer?

Este es el codigo:

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST["registrar"])){

    
        $username = !empty($_POST['user']) ? $_POST['user'] : NULL;
        $email = !empty($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : NULL;
        $password = !empty($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : NULL;
            

        if ($username && $email && $password) {
            include ("connect.php");

            
            if ($connect) {
               
                $username=$connect->real_escape_string($username);
                
                $sqluser = "SELECT idusuarios FROM user WHERE user = '$username' ";
                $resultadouser = $connect->query($sqluser);

    
                if ($resultadouser && $resultadouser->num_rows > 0) {

                    $msg="El usuario ya existe";
                } else {

                    $correo=$connect->real_escape_string($email);
                    $password=$connect->real_escape_string($password);
                    $sqlusuario = "INSERT INTO usuarios(user,email,password)
                    VALUES ('$username', '$correo','$password')";
                    $resultadouser = $connect->query($sqlusuario);


                    if ($resultadouser && $connect->affected_rows > 0){
                        $msg="Registro Exitoso";
                    } else {
                        $msg="Error de consulta INSERT".$connect->error;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $msg="Conexión nula";
            }
        } else {

            $msg="Error. Variables vacías";
        }
    } else {
        $msg="Error. No hay POST registrar";
    }
    /*
            El código es el mismo
            sólo cambia el contenido de $msg
        */

echo "<script>
alert($msg);
window.location = 'index.php';
</script>";


?>
```

**Encontre la solucion** y me gustaria editar la publicacion para que si a alguien en un futuro le pasa, sepa solucionarlo.

Utilice las mismas variables de mi conexion a la base de datos y de mi form con php. *($username, $email, $password). Todo lo que hice fue cambiar las variables en el connect.php y ahora todos los datos se suben de forma correcta
Muchas gracias a todos

Comment: Puedes hacer un alert() mostrando las variables $username, $correo y $password antes de enviarlas a la base de datos, para verificar que estén llegando los datos correctos enviados por POST?

Comment: o imprime $sqlusuario para ver como crea el query y ya te das cuenta si todos los datos contienen algo.

Comment: Los nombres que recibes en `$_POST[` son iguales a los que tienes en los `textBox` de html?

Comment: Si @Bicho, son iguales

Comment: Lo que me dice al mostrar las variables enviadas es lo siguiente:

Primero me dice root (Que es lo que vendria a estar en usuario), Luego me dice mi email de forma correcta, Pero luego esta en blanco, que es donde tendria que estar el password

Comment: 1. Déjanos ver tu archivo connect.php para verificar que todo este ok. 2. Déjanos ver el archivo del formulario para ver si los datos están correctamente nombrados con su respectivo name.

Comment: @RicardoSauceda El valor de usuario siempre es root, y el de password esta en blanco

Comment: No utilizo Jquery

Comment: Creo que se cual es el problema, mi conexion ocupa las variables username y password, se sobreescriben los datos luego de llamar a el file connect.php. Voy a probar y subo la respuesta

Comment: Edito el archivo para subir la respuesta, supe encontrar el error, muchas gracias a todos, sin su ayuda no hubiera podido